# iText-5.0.2.jar - "An error exists on this page" after opening pdf in AR XI

Tags: pdf, itext

I have written a program for adding small table into specific place in the pdf document. The program worked ok for a few years. But now after opening the pdf file modified by this program in Acrobat Reader (11.0.19) the following error appears:

> An error exists on this page. Acrobat may not display the page
>   correctly. Please contact the person who created the PDF document to
>   correct the problem

We observed it after upgrade AR from lower version. 
I searched answers on similar problem but I couldn't find the mentioned errors in my code. Can anyone help me, please?

```
PdfStamper rm_stamper = new PdfStamper(rm_reader, new FileOutputStream(UserCommonDetails.getPropertyValue("FILES_TO_SEND") + outputFilename));
rm_stamper.setEncryption(haslo.trim().getBytes(), "JACEK".getBytes(), PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING|PdfWriter.ALLOW_COPY, PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128);
PdfWriter rm_writer = rm_stamper.getWriter();
Rectangle rm_rect = rm_writer.getPageSize();


PdfPTable rm_table = new PdfPTable(widths);
rm_table.getDefaultCell().setFixedHeight(50);

rm_table.addCell(createLabelCell("NUMBER"));
rm_table.addCell(createDataCell(""+ number));
rm_table.addCell(createLabelCell("NAME"));
rm_table.addCell(createDataCell("" + dk_rm.getName() + " " + dk_rm.getName2()));
rm_table.addCell(createLabelCell("Strategiy"));
rm_table.addCell(createDataCell("" + str_descr));
rm_table.addCell(createLabelCell("Datee"));
rm_table.addCell(createDataCell("" + day));
rm_table.addCell(createLabelCell("Prepade"));
rm_table.addCell(createDataCell("" + get_Name(auhtor)));
rm_table.setTotalWidth(520);

PdfContentByte rm_cb = rm_stamper.getOverContent(RM_table_page);
rm_cb.saveState(); // q
rm_cb.beginText(); // BT
rm_cb.moveText(36, 100); // 36 806 Td
rm_table.writeSelectedRows(0,6,35f, rm_rect.getHeight()-320,rm_cb);
rm_cb.setFontAndSize(bf, 12); // /F1 12 Tf

rm_cb.endText(); // ET
rm_cb.restoreState(); // Q
rm_stamper.close();

indexList.add(new IndexData("EMW", dk_rm.getEmw().trim(), outputFilename, dk_rm.getPowitanie(), dk_rm.getRachunek(),""));
if (trace==1) log.info("Dodano dane do pliku index.dat.pdf dla rachunku: " + dk_rm.getRachunek());
```

Comment: I forgot to say that table displays correct but the message is annoying.

Comment: Part of your code is outside the code block. Can you try again with iText 5.5.11?

Comment: Thanks for answer. Yes I have just tried to use higher version of library including 5.5.11 but there was a problem to check functionality because some packages were no longer available, for example com.itextpdf.text.*  and then many classes couldn't be resolved. I will try to find the new packages paths and then check it again.

Comment: Ok, my fault. I added zip file into build path and so the imports were unavailable. After adding just itext5-itextpdf-5.5.11.jar the project has been built. But the created pdf file was empty (0 bytes). How can I check why the file doesn't create?

Comment: Any exception anywhere? Furthermore, can you share a sample of the files for which you observe the issue?

Comment: Hi. I set catch on following exception path: DocumentException, IOException and Exception. No message appeared.

Comment: I can't share a sample of original files and try to make them from empty template but the error doesn't appear now. Summarizing: The original template opens ok and the empty template opens ok. The original pdf + added table opens with error message, the empty template + table opens ok. Quite strange...